# Matching Contact to User contact

Tags: visualforce

Custom Object Application. Locked by field on application (Lookup to contact)
Contact related to User.

Requirement

Pageblock table has list of application.
2 columns - Application Name and Edit button

The edit button should follow this logic
1. if Application is Locked by the Contact related to logged in user.. take the user to edit page
   else
    Display error message who has locked the application

```
public with sharing class testEditApplication {
public testEditApplication ()
{lstApplication=[SELECT Name, Locked_By__r.Name,status__c
                        FROM Application__c;}public pageReference editApplication() {
    loggedinUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    User user = [Select ContactId from User where Id =: loggedinUserId];
    system.debug('# user.ContactId' + user.ContactId);

    map<Id,Application__c> mapLockedbyConApp = new map<Id,Application__c>();
    Set<Id> LockedByContactIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Application__c application:lstApplication)
    {           
        if(application.Locked_By__c != null)
        { 
            mapLockedbyConApp.put(application.Locked_By__c,application);

        }
        LockedByContactIds.add(application.Locked_By__c); 
    }

    system.debug('# mapLockedbyConApp' + mapLockedbyConApp);
    system.debug('# LockedByContactIds' + LockedByContactIds);

    for(Application__c application:lstApplication)
    {
        system.debug('# user.ContactId' + user.ContactId);
        system.debug('# mapLockedbyConApp.containsKey(user.ContactId)' + mapLockedbyConApp.containsKey(user.ContactId));
        if(mapLockedbyConApp.containsKey(user.ContactId))
        {
            PageReference ProcessApplicationPage = new Pagereference('/apex/ProcessApplication');
            ProcessApplicationPage.getParameters().put('id',application.Id);
            ProcessApplicationPage.setRedirect(true);
            return ProcessApplicationPage;      
        }
        else    
        {
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Record is Locked by ');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Visualforce page code

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstApplication}" var="application">
    <apex:column headerValue="APPLICATION NAME">
        <apex:outputText value="{!application.Name}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="ACTION">
        <apex:commandButton value="edit" disabled="{!IF(application.Status__c == 'Draft',False,True)}" action="{!editApplication}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

How do i iterate over all applications in lst to check if Locked by of each application matches contact of logged in user.

if(mapLockedbyConApp.containsKey(user.ContactId)) -- This code is giving me true for each value...and not iterating each application.

Do you want me to Elaborate on this?

Comment: Do you need some more specific question. or should i elaborate on this

Comment: I typically see the use of a wrapper class to perform a specific action on an item in a list that is being iterated over, as well as a CommandLink

Answer (score 1):

Its working now..
Used command Link and pass parameter of application id to it...worked charms

Comment: TestNS if you'd post the changes you've made and accept your own answer this could help others facing similar issues in the future.